# Delete attachments from Outlook's sent messages

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a huge amount of sent email containing attachments that I no longer need.

I know that I can open each message manually and remove each attachment, but I can't possibly do this for several 100 messages without injury or loss of income.

Is there some way to aggregate / automate attachment removal?

- Large emails can be found from `File > Info > Mailbox Cleanup > Find items larger than`
- I want to somehow select all and remove only the attachments and not delete the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with 3rd Party addons, here are a couple - [Kopf Outlook Attachment Remover](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13880_3-9956705-68.html) or [Attachment Save](http://www.sperrysoftware.com/Outlook/Attachment-Save.asp?Source=RS). Both move the attachment to an external location and replace the entry with the link, not quite what you want, but might be close enough. [Outlook Attachment Sniffer](http://www.rsbr.de/Software/OASniffer/index.htm) Seems to have the option to just "Remove" the attachment.

Alternatively, if you are in the mood to go scripting, there is [this](http://jussi.ruokomaki.fi/tech/173/outlook-remove-attachments-bulkbatch-use-vba/)

Comment: The Kopf one looked promising but didn't work for Outlook 2010. The Attachment save one, I can install (it's in the list of addons) but is not present anywhere. It should be supported, but the examples all show older versions. The script might be a better solutions, but I guess I'll have to read through it first ;). Anyway, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You are welcome. Did you try the 3rd addon, it seems quite up to date.

Comment: Ah it is a 30 day trial..

Comment: The last one worked, but it also deleted all the emails. As I've given this more thought, the question might be a little silly. What I'd have to do is modify the email on the server to remove the attachment, not solve it in the application. It would keep downloading the attachments to be consistent. Also, I didn't mention I'm using IMAP. I think your answer is as good as it gets, really. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah yes, i think IMAP does make this more complicated..

Answer (score 0):

These addins no longer work on Outlook 365 (as of nov 2023). It's much easier to create a VBA macro.

The macro below will delete all attachments from the emails that you have currently selected.

Follow these steps to implement and run the macro:

1. **Open Outlook**: Start Microsoft Outlook on your computer.
2. **Access the VBA Editor**:

   - Press `Alt + F11` to open the VBA editor.
   - In the VBA editor, go to `Insert` > `Module` to open a new module.
3. **Paste the Macro**:

   - Copy the following VBA code and paste it into the module you just opened.

   ```
   Sub DeleteAttachmentsFromSelectedMails()
       Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
       Dim objItem As Object
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
       Dim intCount As Integer

       ' Get the collection of selected objects
       Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

       For Each objItem In objSelection
           ' Check if the selected item is a mail item
           If objItem.Class = olMail Then
               Set objMail = objItem
               Set objAttachments = objMail.Attachments
               intCount = objAttachments.Count

               ' Loop through the attachments and remove them
               While intCount > 0
                   objAttachments.Item(1).Delete
                   intCount = intCount - 1
               Wend

               ' Save the mail item
               objMail.Save
           End If
       Next

       MsgBox "Attachments removed from selected emails.", vbInformation
   End Sub
   ```
4. **Run the Macro**:

   - Close the VBA editor.
   - In Outlook, select the emails from which you want to remove attachments.
   - Press `Alt + F8`, select `DeleteAttachmentsFromSelectedMails`, and then click `Run`.
   - You can also customize the Ribbon to add a button with this Macro

**Important Notes**:

- **Backup Emails**: Before running this macro, it's a good idea to backup your emails, as this process is irreversible. There are no confirmation steps. When you launch the macro, it immediately deletes all attachments for all selected emails.
- **Macro Security Settings**: Depending on your macro security settings, you might need to enable macros or add your VBA project as a trusted source.
- **Version Compatibility**: This macro is intended for use in Microsoft Outlook 365 (as ov Nov 2023). It may not be compatible with all versions of Outlook, so you might need to adjust it for your specific version.