# Removing attachments from Outlook 2013 items

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, attachments

First off I have seen these two questions:

- [Strip attachments from emails to disk but leave a link in the email to the attachment](https://superuser.com/questions/51133/strip-attachments-from-emails-to-disk-but-leave-a-link-in-the-email-to-the-attac#)
- [Delete attachments from Outlook's sent messages](https://superuser.com/questions/510617/delete-attachments-from-outlooks-sent-messages)

I am looking to perform a similar function. I want to remove attachments from emails (sent or received) so that I can save the original email to a shared network folder. The reason I want to remove the attachments is that they will already be saved in other folders, but since others will be using the folder they need access to the original message for reply, forwards, etc.

In addition, the answers provided in the linked questions seem to only work for older versions of Outlook. **I am looking for a way to remove attachments from Outlook 2013 emails.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that in Outlook 2013 there is a built-in function this is accessed by right-clicking on the attachment. [image: example]

The steps would be:

1. Open saved email
2. Right-click on attachment
3. Click "Remove Attachment"
4. Re-Save email to desired location

Answer (score 1):

You can delete an email attachment by selecting the attachment and pressing the **Delete** button on your keyboard.

> 1. Click the file that you want to delete in the **Attached** box.
>
> [image]
>
> 2. Press Delete on your keyboard to remove the attachment.

Source: [Remove an attachment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-an-attachment-404ad04f-6168-4453-a974-d8a95c42b07a)

Answer (score 1):

There is a free [Remove Outlook Attachments](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAttachmentsRemove) utility that can do that in bulk. You can also [save all attachments](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAttachmentsSave) to any location before removing them. There are also free tools for replacing attachments with links.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend these tools because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.