# Remove attachments from all emails in a folder (Outlook for Mac)

Tags: mac, email, microsoft-outlook, attachments

I'm looking for a tool to strip email attachments from my archived folders on Outlook for Mac (Version 16.20).

I am aware that [such a solution exists for PC users](https://superuser.com/questions/1191651/removing-attachments-from-outlook-2013-items), but have not found anything for Mac users.

I have emails archived going back to 2010, and although I'd like to keep the messages, I need to free up space, so would like to strip away the attachments.

I note also that there are some solutions involving VBA code, but nothing (that I'm aware of) that's applicable to the latest version of Outlook.

Finally, I'm also aware that this can be done one email at a time, but with tens of thousands of messages to process, this is clearly not an option.

**Note**: I would expect that a solution would remove the items not just from local storage, but permanently from the server. The email account in question is a Microsoft Office 365 account, so a solution involving doing this from the server side is another possibility.

Comment: Do you mean VBA code? You can post this forum to see if anyone know this. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=outlookdev

Answer (score 1):

The article
[How to clean up Outlook attachments](https://macpaw.com/how-to/remove-outlook-attachments)
suggests several methods of cleaning up on attachments:

- In Office 2016, attachments are located in the `Outlook Temp` folder,
  and the article suggests some methods of locating that folder,
  from which you may drag them to the Trash.
- In versions prior to Outlook 2016, the attachments are stored in the folder
  `~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/Outlook Temp`.
- The application
  [CleanMyMac X](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) (commercial with trial period),
  downloadable from [here](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac),
  can find and delete Outlook attachments.

(Note: I do not possess a Mac and cannot verify the above.)

Comment: Wouldn't this just remove the files from the computer; i.e. in the future if I run Outlook on another computer, it would just re-download all the attachments again from the server?

Comment: I think this will only happen if you open the containing email, but you can verify it easily.

Comment: Thanks for the solution – but I'm afraid this doesn't delete the items from the server, which is the source of the real problem I'm having (too much data on the server).

Comment: That request was added after my answer was posted. I think it is different from the problem of removing attachments from local email.