# In MS Outlook, how to remove unlisted attachment?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, attachments

Environment: MS Office LTSC Pro Plus 2021 under Windows 11 Pro 64.

I have the following e-mail in my inbox due to an error in the recipient address of a previous e-mail:

[image]

At the top of this image, the listing of this e-mail includes the attachment icon and the size is indicated as 512 kb. In the display of the e-mail itself, there is supposed to be a list of attachments after the headers, but no attachment is indicated.

When there is a list of attachments after the headers, each attachment has a drop-down menu that includes "Remove Attachment". This process is [illustrated in a SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1191651/removing-attachments-from-outlook-2013-items/#1193227). That is the only way I know of to remove an attachment from a received e-mail.

I want to keep this e-mail in Outlook, but without the attachment. How can I remove this attachment when it is not listed with a menu that includes "Remove Attachment"?

Comment: Try using *Actions > Edit message*.

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen that capability before. To find it, I had to open another message in a window, then, in the menu at the top, click on the three dots at the right end of it to get more menu entries, which included `Actions`. But when I open the e-mail that I was asking about, there is no `Actions` in the menu.

Comment: You cannot delete the attachment at the OWA, this feature is only available in Outlook for Windows, see: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/remove-attachment-with-outlook-on-the-web-owa/d37feb9c-a207-4b54-92f2-d51798799cb1

Comment: @Faery - Your link says that OWA = Outlook on the Web. I'm not using that. As stated in the first line of the question, I'm using MS Office Pro in Windows. Outlook is running on my computer, not on the Web or "in the cloud."